# Is that SQL query exploitable for really malicious things

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I have following SQL query in my WordPress plugin,

```
SELECT `ID`, `post_content` 
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_type` = 'movie' 
AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
OR `post_status` = 'private' 
AND `ID` NOT IN ($data) 
ORDER BY `ID` 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

`$data` is fully raw input not escaped. I can execute subqueries at `$data` position like so,

```
1,2) AND (SELECT sleep(5)) AND `post_title` NOT IN (1
```

Generated state:

```
SELECT `ID`, `post_content` 
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_type` = 'movie' 
AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
OR `post_status` = 'private' 
AND `ID` NOT IN (1,2) AND (SELECT sleep(5)) AND `post_title` NOT IN (1) 
ORDER BY `ID` 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

But I'm still wondering is that query exploitable with another SQL statements for malicious attacks like drop table or fetch another table data or something. If is it, how it could achieve and with what a payload? Thanks.

Comment: Whether it can be used for _modifications_ depends on other config details (primarily, if multiple statements are allowed per invocation).  It can always be attacked for reads, which might be far more damaging.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thank for reply, how it could be that reading data from another table at `$data` position?

Comment: Something like `1) UNION ALL (SELECT -1, <some column> FROM <wherever you want>`.  Essentially you can make whatever kind of second subquery you want, and it can extract your entire db - if this gets caught by one of the many automated scripts trawling the internet, it'll happen in short order (if this is already deployed, it may already have happened).

Comment: I mean that query starting with `SELECT ID, post_content FROM wp_posts..` and when we put some subquery at the variable position, I think it's not possible to get results from another table that different from `wp_posts`. So when I try your `UNION` statement; I still get data from `wp_posts`. I wonder is there no way to get data from another table.

Comment: You get data from `wp_posts` *and* from whatever other table you want. Download `sqlmap` and point it to the page you'd like to test. As per your question, that is most definitely exploitable.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers could you give me some example payload for use `SELECT` statement to get any data from another table at that point to reflect the query result exactly, thanks.

Comment: Probably exploitable only using data retrieval sentences like `SELECT` but that should be fairly easy to achieve (check @Clockwork-Muse comment). First step would be [getting the table names of the mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql), and once there you could retrieve any interesting data depending on how the database was designed.

Comment: Consider this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f8ee9/2/0) - `1) union all select id, username from users where (1=1`

Comment: Thank you @LievenKeersmaekers, do you think can we also execute `INSERT INTO` or `UPDATE` at that position?

Comment: @User9123 - You could try `1); update users set username = 'Potter';select * from users where (1=1`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers thank you but multi queries not supported like after `;`

Comment: Not supported by what actually? The mysql client you/wordpress is using? If that's the case, I don't know an attack vector that could change data but being able to read your entire database should be enough of a vulnerability on itself mind you ;)